# Are disjoint edges the same as matchings?

Tags: approximation, vertex-cover

I am reading *Chapter 9 Approximation Algorithms* of Dasgupts et al.'s *Algorithm* book for vertex cover approximation and they bring up the concept of **matchings**.

To support this, I am also watching Coursera's *Approximation algorithms* course by EIT digital.

This [video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/approximation-algorithms/lecture/uXroX/an-approximation-algorithm-for-vertex-cover) mentions using **disjoint edges** and would like to confirm that the **2** are actually the same and I am not missing and subtle details.

[image: Coursera's algorithm]

Answer (score 2):

Two disjoint edges $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are edges that do not share any endpoint, i.e., $\{a,b\} \cap \{c,d\} = \emptyset$. A matching is a set of *pairwise* disjoint edges.

Comment: Still not clear. Are they different or the same?

Comment: What does **pairwise** mean/add here? I see each edge as connecting a **pair** of vertices.

Comment: Pairwise means that the condition holds for any distinct pair of edges in the matching.
Formally, a set $M$ of edges is a matching if $\forall e_1 = (a,b) \in M, \forall e_2 = (c,d) \in M$, if $e_1 \neq e_2$ then $\{a,b\} \cap \{c,d\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: I am still unclear. The math text is what I don't get. 

Disjoint edges don't share any vertices but a matching is a set of edges such that each pair of edges picked from the set is disjoint?

Comment: Yes. What's unclear about that? Being disjoint is a property about pairs of edges. A matching is a set in which each distinct pair of edges satisfies that property.

Comment: They all seemed to be the same. However, comment above clarified things.